# Angular Firestore - Get document ID as a property to use it again in an other function - Typescript

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic-framework, google-cloud-firestore, mobile-development

So here is my code :

```
getOutfitsCollectionData(): Promise<any> {
    let outfitsRef = this.afStore.collection('outfits');
    let allOutfits = outfitsRef.snapshotChanges().pipe(
        map(actions=>{
            return actions.map(a=>{
                const id = a.payload.doc.id;
                return id
            })
        })
    )
    let outfitsID =  allOutfits.forEach(outID=>{
        console.log(outID)
        return outID
    })
    return outfitsID
}
}
```

When I do this part

```
let outfitsID =  allOutfits.forEach(outID=>{
        console.log(outID)
        return outID
    })
```

The console is giving me this :

[console perfect](https://i.stack.imgur.com/20WEP.png)

It's exactly what I want, I just want to rename the array and set it as the result of my function but every console.log I put under these lines doesn't do anything so it seems that every line under isn't doing anything.

If I'm not clear, tell me guys !

What I'm trying to do is get each documents id of my collection to use it in an other function on the same tab.

I think that it might be easier to create a service but I don't really know how to do it.

Please don't make me ban one more time, I'm just trying to learn ... It won't be really smart to send me to a really general subject.

I'm not just trying to have pro that give a code that works, I want to understand and get better.

Thanks for your help guys !

( BTW sorry for my bad English, I'm French :) )

**So just a little edit :**

I tried this code, I don't really understand why when I console.log allOutfits, I'm not getting the good value :

```
async getOutfitsCollectionData(){
    let outfitsRef = this.afStore.collection('outfits');
    let allOutfits = await outfitsRef.get().toPromise().then((step)=>{
        return step.forEach(doc=>{
        if (!doc.exists){
            console.log('Zut !')
        }else{
            console.log(doc.id)
            return doc.id
        }
    })
})
.catch(err=>{
    console.log('Error getting outfits', err)
})
console.log(allOutfits)
return allOutfits
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've finished my app long time ago, but I think that might interest.

I finally decided to learn typescript lol.

You can't get a value of a promise since it's not return, that was what I was trying to do.

Just call your function and .then do what you want ^^.

By the way, I needed to map my data as said by Lim Shang Yi

Answer (score 0):

Problem lies in this code:

```
return step.forEach(doc=>{
        if (!doc.exists){
            console.log('Zut !')
        }else{
            console.log(doc.id)
            return doc.id
        }
```

`step` is a [`QuerySnapshot`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.firestore.QuerySnapshot#docs) so you should access the documents using `step.docs`. The function `forEach` does not return you the the array, but returns undefined instead. 
use `map` which actually returns the transformed data:

```
return steps.docs.map(doc => doc.id);
```

Comment: Hi, thank you really much for your answer, when I try this this is telling me this :Property 'map' does not exist on type 'QuerySnapshot<DocumentData>'

Comment: @OpiumPython I have updated the answer to reflect your comment

Comment: Perfect, it's working ! I've got my promise with the good value !! Thank you so much, I've just add to change this : return steps.docs().map(doc => doc.id); to this : return steps.docs.map(doc => doc.id) but it wasn't a big issue ;), thank you really much !!!!!